# View pager which can scroll from half to fullscreen

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, fullscreen

I want to implement a viewpager which will initially occupy half of the screen(bottom half),top half will have some other content. The user can scroll the viewpager upwards to fill the screen with view pager content. If he wants to see the initial content at the top half he can scroll down the viewpager again. How can I implement this? Example will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use BottomSheet Fragment for this kind of design

There is a tutorial available [here](http://www.androidauthority.com/bottom-sheets-707252/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bottomsheet to achieve this. Here is a sample tutorial :

https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031

You can put view pager inside your bottomsheet and set initial peek height of bottom sheet as per your requirements.